# 126:Incorrect key file for table error appearing

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

I'm getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  126:Incorrect key file for table '/dev/shm/#sql_c40_0.MYI'; try to repair it :: SELECT (SELECT p.products_price  FROM (products p, products_description pd, products_to_categories p2c ) ORDER BY p.products_price LIMIT 1) AS low, (SELECT p.products_price  FROM (products p, products_description pd, products_to_categories p2c ) ORDER BY p.products_price DESC LIMIT 1) AS high in /hsphere/local/home/xxxxx/includes/classes/db/mysql/query_factory.php on line 101

I thought maybe the above SQL was incorrect but when developing on my localhost I wasn't getting any error of the sort. I've read on here and elsewhere that it could be a tmp table size problem on the server but by host says that it's unlikely to be a server error and want to charge me money to investigate

I'm using a zencart 1.5 if that makes any difference at all.

Does anyone have ideas on what I could try to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to attempt to repair your tables. You can do this by connecting to your database via your command line, phpMyAdmin or through some sort of GUI.

I'll assume your host possibly provide phpMyAdmin access, so try that first as it's relative simple to check your tables.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I followed the advice in the answer above, ie I went to phpmyadmin and did the REPAIR TABLE `products`; commands which went ok. It said the qureys had been executed ok. But I notice I'm still getting the errors in my cache. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing what it says. Try to run a [repair](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) on the tables and see if it doesn't fix the issue::

```
REPAIR TABLE `products`;
REPAIR TABLE `products_description`;
REPAIR TABLE `products_to_categories`;
```

Comment: Ok I've given this a go so I'll have to wait and see if any more errors appear. How could this have happened?

Comment: You might also have a utility in your CPanel that allows you to repair tables (in the section that deals with Databases).

Comment: @ scott I've tried to repair using the above commands in phpmyadmin and the query was run ok. I waited and didn't see any more errors being logged for the following couple of hours but after a couple of days I'm having the problem again. What else could be the matter

Comment: @SamuelCook that comment is very misleading and vague. With code, there is always a reason. downvote

Comment: @BrianLeach agreed